# pd.Grouper() when applied on datetime, changes the original column of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have a sample dataframe from my huge dataframe as shown given below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

NaN = np.nan
data = {
    'ID':['AAQRB','AAQRB','AAQRB', 
'AHXSJ','AHXSJ','AHXSJ','GABOY','GABOY','GABOY','GHZGS','GHZGS','GHZGS'],
    'Date':['10/18/2021  10:52:53 PM','10/18/2021  10:53:55 PM', '10/25/2021  5:55:43 PM',
           '10/22/2021  10:37:06 PM','10/22/2021  10:38:22 PM','10/22/2021  10:39:56 PM',
           '11/1/2021  1:27:15 AM','11/1/2021  1:28:45 AM','11/2/2021  8:53:39 PM',
           '10/29/2021  11:13:57 PM', '10/29/2021  11:17:47 PM', '10/29/2021  11:19:15 PM'], 
    'Race_x':[NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,1, NaN,NaN,1],
    'Vaccine':['TRUE',NaN,NaN,'TRUE',NaN,NaN,'TRUE',NaN,NaN,'FALSE',NaN,NaN],
    'Study_activity': 
   [NaN,'continue',NaN,NaN,'continue',NaN,NaN,'continue',NaN,NaN,'continue',NaN],
    'Who_Contacted': 
   [NaN,NaN,'WeContacted',NaN,NaN,'WeContacted',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'WeContacted']}

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Goal is to get all the first values for each ID and filter the several rows of participant to a single row with all information. The final dataframe should look like the image given below.

[image]

**CODE TRIED**

I tried using the Grouper() function, and the code is given below.

```
test_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['Date'])

test_df1 = (test_df.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')])
   .agg("first")
   .reset_index())
 baseline_df = test_df1[~test_df1.duplicated(subset = ['ID'], keep='first')]
```

But the problem with this is, if I use freq='D', then the Race_x values are missed which are entered the next day. the output looks like the image shown below.

[image]

If I use freq='M' or freq='Y', the other values are captured, however the Dates column values are changed, and we get the date of end of month for each ID as shown below.

[image]

The final 'Date' column should be the first entry of the 'date' for each ID and it should not change.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a virtual column to group by month:

```
>>> test_df.assign(month=test_df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')) \
           .groupby(['ID', 'month']).agg('first') \
           .droplevel(1).reset_index() \
           .assign(Date=lambda x: x['Date'].dt.date)

      ID        Date  Race_x Vaccine Study_activity Who_Contacted
0  AAQRB  2021-10-18     NaN    TRUE       continue   WeContacted
1  AHXSJ  2021-10-22     1.0    TRUE       continue   WeContacted
2  GABOY  2021-11-01     1.0    TRUE       continue          None
3  GHZGS  2021-10-29     1.0   FALSE       continue   WeContacted
```

Comment: This gives 2 or 3 rows for each ID. My goal is to get a single row for each participant. This is just a sample of huge dataset, and there are atleast 30 entries for each ID, which have to be consolidated to a single row.

Comment: Do what you want in your agg function but your problem is `pd.Grouper`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. It is. Even after I filter to the format you have given above, it will be the same issue.

Comment: Can this be done for 'year' instead of month? And get the same result? If so, what has to be changed in the code?

Comment: I'll try later but my first thought is to change 'month' by 'year' and '%Y-%m' by '%Y'.

Comment: yes. its correct. I did it and works well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to `groupby` ID only and aggregate `Date` as first, everything else as whenever you have a valid value.

Assuming all of `Race_x`, `Vaccine`, `Study_activity`, `Who_Contacted` is always a single non-NaN value for an ID.  You can `bfill` first before aggregation.

This will collect the non-NaN value to the first entry for a participant.

```
test_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime('Date').dt.date
test_df.update(test_df.groupby('ID').bfill())
```

Then, try aggregation.

```
test_df.groupby('ID').first().reset_index()


>>>     ID        Date Race_x Vaccine Study_activity Who_Contacted
 0   AAQRB  2021-10-18    NaN    TRUE       continue WeContacted
 1   AHXSJ  2021-10-22    1.0    TRUE       continue WeContacted
 2   GABOY  2021-11-01    1.0    TRUE       continue       NaN
 3   GHZGS  2021-10-29    1.0   FALSE       continue WeContacted
```

Comment: Nice solution. But unfortunately, it does not provide the required solution for the original dataset. The final solution looks something like what Corralien has in his solution.

Comment: Could you post your expected result?  I thought you need a single row per ID.

Comment: Yes I do, but the original dataset is not single non-NaN value. The values may be repeated in subsequent rows. I think this is the reason backfill() is not working.
 The expected result  is given in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  This solution is achieving "get all the first values for each ID".  By doing `bfill` per ID, the first non-NaN value is always comes to the first row for the ID.  This result looks exactly the same as your expected result. I am missing something?  Maybe, the sample is not a representative for a scenario for multiple non-NaN values.